# With React-Router, can you set an "outer" component to render at every route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was originally using [ButtermilkJS](https://buttermilk.js.org/) for routing and its Router accepts an outerComponent prop which you can set to render at every route.

So, for example, in the following code, `Base` is a component with a navbar and some css for the website background (things that I will want on every page, regardless of other content), and the Home and Kittens components are passed to it as children props when the user navigates to the / home or /kittens routes.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, RoutingState, Link } from 'buttermilk';
import Home from './HomePage';
import Kittens from './KittenPage';

const routes = [
          {
            path: '/',
            render: () => Home,
          },
          {
            path: '/kittens',
            render: () => Kittens
          }];

const Base () => (
            <div className="base-page">
              <header>
                <Menu />
              </header>
              {this.props.children}
            </div>
          );


ReactDOM.render(<Router 
                routes={routes} 
                outerComponent={Base} />, root);
```

Is there a way to do something similar with react-router? This seems like a really handy mechanic.

Comment: You are importing and defining `Base` in your example

Comment: Fixed. Just throwing together a quick example to try and give a sketch of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try creating a Higher Order Component that will enable you to wrap whatever you like with `Base`

```
import React from 'react';

const higherOrderComponent = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class Base extends React.Component {
      render() {
          //do your base stuff here
          return <WrappedComponent />;
      }
  }

  return Base;
};

const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        render: () => higherOrderComponent(Home),
      },
      {
        path: '/kittens',
        render: () => higherOrderComponent(Kittens)
      }];
```

Here are the React Docs for HOCs: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html